# Spring cloud security vs Spring security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud-security

I just started learning spring cloud security and I have a basic question. How it is different from spring security? Do we need our application to be built on spring boot for using spring cloud security?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `spring-cloud-security` builds on `spring-boot` and `spring-security` and provides some annotations and extra tools for OAuth2, especially useful for Single Sign On and when making use of the Zuul proxy (also part of the `spring-cloud` suite).

Answer (score 1):

Spring Security is a stand alone framework within Spring Framework. Spring Cloud Security is a Cloud Container and MicroServices focused Security Framework that provides Tokenised Security for Spring Boot applications.